# Erlang generic foldl/3 equivalent for binary trees

Tags: erlang, binary-tree

I need to write the equivalent of [lists:foldl/3](https://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3) for binary trees.

Every node is represented as:

`[Value, LeftNode, RightNode]`

So a tree with a root 2 and leaves 1 and 3 would look like this:
`[2, [1, [], []], [3, [], []]]`

Later I want to use that function to perform operations, such as summing up all positive values in that tree etc.

This is the function I wrote:

```
tree_foldl(_, Acc, []) -> Acc;
tree_foldl(Fun, Acc, [V, L, R]) ->
X1 = tree_foldl(Fun, Fun(V, Acc), L),
X2 = tree_foldl(Fun, Fun(L, X1), R),
X2.
```

the problem is that it's not truly generic, and when we have, let's say a tree with only a root, e.g.:
`[2, [], []]`

it calls both `Fun(2, 0)` and `Fun([], 2)` and when trying to sum up the values in the second case it tries to do [] + 2, which is an invalid expression. It also would break on more complicated cases.

I would greatly appreciate any help with fixing this function. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should use tuples as nodes in this case instead of lists. Lists are linked lists between their elements while tuples use contiguous memory (you can access a single element of a tuple without processing the leading elements of structure).

There's no need for `Fun(L, X1)`:

```erlang
tree_foldl(_, Acc, []) -> Acc;
tree_foldl(Fun, Acc, [V, L, R]) ->
    Acc0 = Fun(V, Acc),
    Acc1 = tree_foldl(Fun, Acc0, L),
    Acc2 = tree_foldl(Fun, Acc1, R),
    Acc2.
```

If the node is empty, do nothing, else run the `Fun` on the node and recurse on both subtrees.